# Page not reloading after writing to file

Tags: express

I'm trying to make simple form submit in express.js. I'm getting the form values, write to file and then redirect to other page. The problem is that when I try to write to file my page is opened but I need to refresh it to load the jquery. Any idea how to solve this?

```
app.post('/installation', function (req, res){
    var body = {
        email: req.body.email,
        firstlastname: req.body.firstlastname,

    }

    filePath = __dirname + '/data.json'
    fs.writeFile(filePath, JSON.stringify(body), function(err) {
        if (err) { throw err }
    })
    res.redirect('/install');
})

app.get('/install',(req,res)=>{

    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'index2.html'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your redirect within the callback of the [`fs.writeFile`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_file_data_options_callback) call, so the page loads only *after* the file has been written:

```js
app.post('/installation', function(req, res) {
    var body = {
        email: req.body.email,
        firstlastname: req.body.firstlastname,
    };

    filePath = __dirname + '/data.json';
    fs.writeFile(filePath, JSON.stringify(body), function(err) {
        if (err) { throw err }

        // Move redirect to inside the callback
        res.redirect('/install');
    });
});

app.get('/install', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'index2.html'));
});
```